# RabbitMQ back up messages in specific queue

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a service that consumes messages from a RabbitMQ queue (posting to the queue is done through a topic exchange). Assuming that the service can theoretically fail and lose its state, possibility to back up all the messages for disaster recovery would come in handy.

The first idea that comes to mind is adding another binding for the topic exchange so that the messages are also posted to another queue, and creating a custom service for backing up messages that would listen on that queue. But this sounds much like a potential reinvention of the wheel. Is there a simpler way to do this with RabbitMQ (plugin/existing service/etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that it's possible to do with a combination of a [firehose](http://www.rabbitmq.com/firehose.html) and a [tracing plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/09/rabbitmq-tracing-a-ui-for-the-firehose/).

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ cluster, as specified in [Clustering Guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) and [Highly Available Queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html) will do what you want in the right way.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing. It's not the RabbitMQ whose failure or availability I'm concerned with. I want to basically back up traffic going through certain queues for future, not to solve any immediate availability problems.

Comment: Then duplicating messages to backup queue as you noted in question is the most appropriate way. P.S. "service can theoretically fail" in question really sounds like broker failure. If not - please specify what do you mean.